# How to suppress new SMS notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing my own SMS messenger and I need to completely suppress new SMS notification raised by default stock messenger. For sure I'm intercepting incoming SMS notification and aborting `Broadcast` through `BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()`, like:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Map<String, String> msgs = retrieveMessages(intent);
        for (String address : msgs.keySet()) {
            String msg = msgs.get(address);
            Log.i(TAG, "New sms received=" + msg);
            //saving message in phone
            Message message = Message.createIncomingMessage(address, msg);
            message.setSeen(1); ////mark message seen, so stock messenger couldn't arose notification
            message.setRead(1); //mark message read, so stock messenger couldn't report it as unread
            message.setUnread(true); //mark message unread for our messenger
            message = Me.getMe().getMessageDAO().save(context, message); //saving message 
            SmsReceiver.updateNotification(context, message, true, true); //raise notification from "our" messenger
        }
        //aborting default broadcast, since everything already done and no need to do more
        this.abortBroadcast();
    }
```

Everything works as planned. But whenever I'm inserting new SMS into database through `Me.getMe().getMessageDAO().save(context, message);` within few seconds stock messenger somehow is being notified about new message in database and again raises notification.

Question is: how to suppress this notification?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to set `priority` of your receiver [see docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority).

secondly, call `abortBroadCast` before you do heavy processing task(storing into DB).

or you can try this db storing thing in a thread, Start the thread and call `abortBroadcast()` immediately.

Comment: 1) I've set priority highest priority 

2) `abortBroadcast` in most cases works as it has to be, but problem occurs if user doesn't open my notification for while - let's say several minutes. I suspect that another broadcast triggered by system